# Jenkins: Configure AD Plugin Authorization with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am working on configuring Active Directory via Groovy.
I was able to authenticate via active directory via the UI meaning ports and authentication is not the issue.
I have the following based on the LDAP plugin:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.*
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*
import hudson.*
import jenkins.*

String domain = 'my.domain.com'
String site = ''
String server = '192.168.1.1'
String bindName = 'account@my.domain.com'
String bindPassword = 'password'

SecurityRealm ad_realm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)
jenkins.instance.setSecurityRealm(ad_realm)
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: jenkins_script[add_active_directory] (jenkins_wrapper::ldap line 32) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
   ---- Begin output of "/opt/java/latest/bin/java" -jar "/tmp/kitchen/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /tmp/groovy20160208-28479-azdr83 ----
   STDOUT: 
   STDERR: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: RemoteClass
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at RemoteClass.run(RemoteClass:16)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:517)
    at hudson.cli.GroovyCommand.run(GroovyCommand.java:86)
    at hudson.cli.CLICommand.main(CLICommand.java:237)
    at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl.main(CliManagerImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:608)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:583)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:542)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl$1.call(CliManagerImpl.java:63)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorAdapter.call(CallableDecoratorAdapter.java:18)
   atorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any insight on this error?

**UPDATED**

New Code

```
import jenkins.model.*
    import hudson.model.*
    import hudson.security.*
    import hudson.plugins.*
    import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*
    import hudson.*
    import jenkins.*

    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    String domain = 'my.domain.com'
    String site = ''
    String server = '1.2.3.4'
    String bindName = 'bind@my.domain.com'
    String bindPassword = '#{bind_password}'
    adrealm = ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)
    instance.setSecurityRealm(adrealm)
```

New error

```
STDERR: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: RemoteClass.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [my.domain.com, , account@my.domain.com, ...]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
            at RemoteClass.run(RemoteClass:15)
            at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)
            at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:517)
            at hudson.cli.GroovyCommand.run(GroovyCommand.java:86)
            at hudson.cli.CLICommand.main(CLICommand.java:237)
            at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl.main(CliManagerImpl.java:92)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:608)
            at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:583)
            at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:542)
            at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
            at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
            at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
            at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
            at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl$1.call(CliManagerImpl.java:63)
            at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorAdapter.call(CallableDecoratorAdapter.java:18)
            at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
            at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try adding "import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*"

Comment: @JérémieB Added the line and am getting the same error

Comment: Could you show code of RemoteClass? (especially line 16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with all of the new additions from suggestions,

Try:

adrealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)

Comment: adrealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)

Error: STDERR: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
           RemoteClass: 15: unable to resolve class ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm 
            @ line 15, column 11.

Comment: So, "site" can't be null...that needs to have a value. I was able to run that code and it worked. Also, you don't need to import all of those classes:


`import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*


def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

String domain = 'my.domain.com'
String site = 'site'
String server = '1.2.3.4'
String bindName = 'bind@my.domain.com'
String bindPassword = '#{bind_password}'

adrealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)

instance.setSecurityRealm(adrealm)`

Answer (score 0):

You never created a Jenkins object.
I think normally you'd have something like
def j = Jenkins.getInstance()
j.setSecurityRealm(ad_realm)

Comment: Thanks for the response, tried your suggestion and got a different error which I added above